# How to get the MAX value of unique column in sql and aggregate other?

Tags: sql

I want get the row with max 'date', groupy just by unique 'id' but without considering another columns.

I tried this query:
(But don't work cause modify anothers columns)

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(num),
       MAX(date),-- I just want the max of this column
       MAX(product_name),
       MAX(other_columns)
FROM TB
GROUP BY id
```

Table:

```
id    num      date      product_name   other_columns
123   0001   2021-12-01      exit          12315413
123   0002   2021-12-02      entry         65481328
333   0001   2021-12-03      entry         13848136
333   ASDV   2021-12-04      exit           1325165
```

Expected Result:

```
id    num      date      product_name
123   0002   2021-12-02      entry
333   ASDV   2021-12-04      exit
```

How to do that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You say that you just want max date, but nothing else. But your expected result has num and product_name. What is the logic there?

Comment: Do you want to include other columns? If yes you can't do it with `max()` for each column because exit > entry (x > n), you'll need sub query or cte or join.

Comment: I'm using Transact-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-query with an inner join can take care of this pretty DBMS agnostically.

```
SELECT
      t.ID
      ,t.date
      ,t.product_name
      ,t.other_columns
    FROM tb as t
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT
          id
          ,MAX(date) as date
       FROM tb
       GROUP BY id 
    ) as s on t.id = s.id and t.date = s.date
```

Comment: Made a fiddle for this, but instead of making a duplicate response since you were first, here you go! :)
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rWqj4aFLXnEdYAmvycppa2/0